# AWS S3 Bucket Presigned url issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have written an API to read user posts after the token is passed in the header. API returns many posts at a time with the nested attachment name for images or videos etc. Currently, all attachments are stored in a server folder directory. Attachments is displayed by another API which accept attachment name as a parameter and return attachment url.

Now I want to move on AWS S3 bucket with the same concept with presigned URL.

API is being used on the flutter app.

I created a API which accept user auth token and return upload presigned URL for s3 bucket.

For displaying attachments i am thinking two option.

1. Create a another API which accept attachment name(object key name) and will return presigned URL of that attachment.
2. Post API return json data after replacing all attachment name with presigned URL. But this will take too long for nested json data by looping.

I am new in AWS s3 bucket. Please guide what will be the best way to handle this.

How facebook, twitter, instagram handle private files.

Comment: One minor potential downside of the 2nd option is that all the pre-signed URLs are computed at about the same time. If there is a sufficient period of time between pre-signing and when the client actually presents one or more of the URLs to S3 then they may already have expired. Obviously you may be able to make their expiration time late enough if you can predict the behavior of the client.

Comment: Some potential upsides of the 1st option is that the client is forced to request the pre-signed URLs from you one by one at the time they are needed so a) they are fresh, b) you can reduce how long they are valid (good security practice) and c) you can track the client behavior more easily (if that's of value to you). Obvious downside is more HTTP requests than strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I see is returning the post data with already generated pre-signed url.

Having a separate api for generating the presigned url would mean

- the system will need to authorize the input anyway (if the user is authorized to access the particular object)
- the user has to wait anyway until the signed links are generared, just with additional call

> this will take too long for nested json data by looping

Not really, generating the presigned url makes no backend / S3 calls, it's just a bunch of HMAC computations. But, as already mentioned, these need to be done regardless which option is chosen